# How to select values where another value is an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select values where another POST values are an array, I do not know what is wrong with my query giving me this error. I'm trying to know what courses are just added to table. I have five inputs in the form.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache\htdocs\xxx\addcourse.php on line 262
```

Here is my code

```
  <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

      $code= isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
      $coursecode = isset($_POST['coursecode']) ? $_POST['coursecode'] : '';
      $both=$code[$x] .' '. $coursecode[$x];

      $sqlcourses = "SELECT * FROM courses where course_code='$both' ORDER BY course_id DESC LIMIT 5 ";
      $resultcourses = $mysqli->query($sqlcourses);


        if ($resultcourses->num_rows > 0) {


            while($row = $resultcourses->fetch_assoc()) {

                ?>
                </p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;  </p>
                <table width="415" border="0">
                <tr>
                <?php
                $courses=$row["course_code"];
                echo $courses;
                ?>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                  </table>
              <?php 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And which line of code is 262?

Comment: I just noticed that I need to edit $both to '$both' in the query. Know no errors,but not giving me any result?

Comment: Your query is failing. At first glance, `$both` contains a space - `$both=$code[$x] .' '. $coursecode[$x];`, so it needs to be wrapped in quotes - `...where course_code='$both'...`.

Comment: your for loop doesn't make sense, `$code` is evaluated up top but defined inside the loop

Comment: Your loop creates multiple queries, with the last one overwriting all the others.

Comment: I have removed the for loop and get Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\Apache\htdocs\xxx\addcourse.php on line 252

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\Apache\htdocs\xxx\addcourse.php on line 252

Comment: The line 252 is $both=$code[$x] .' '. $coursecode[$x];

Comment: `Notice: Undefined offset: 5` tells you that either `$code[5]` or `$coursecode[5]` is not set, most likely `$coursecode[5]`.

Comment: I just fixed it, though I needed the loop. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

First, you build an array of the course codes that you want to retrieve; I'm leaving off the boundary checks for simplicity:

```
$codes = [];
foreach ($_POST['code'] as $k => $code) {
    $codes[] = $code . ' ' . $_POST['coursecode'][$k];
}
```

Then, you prepare the statement you will use:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * 
  FROM courses 
  WHERE course_code = ?
  ORDER BY course_id DESC 
  LIMIT 5");
```

Followed by the main loop:

```
foreach ($codes as $code) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
    assert($stmt->execute());

    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way with small modified code

first you have to convert string to array to get index (x) in array

```
$code = explode(" ", $code);
$course = explode(" ", $coursecode);
foreach ($code as $cd => $x) {
    $both = $code[$x].' '.$coursecode[$x];
    $sqlcourses = "SELECT * FROM courses where course_code='$both' ORDER BY course_id DESC LIMIT 5 ";
    $resultcourses = $mysqli->query($sqlcourses);
}
```

second you can choose variable $code or $course as length of loop based on your case

```
foreach ($course as $crs => $x) {
    your condition...
}
```